# Changing the channel in a Samsung Smart TV App

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I am writing an app with a "picture in picture" object showing what the TV is currently tuned to. The JS used to trigger this is :

```
webapis.tv.window.setRect({
    left:108, top:0, width : 714, height: 420
});
```

however I am not sure how to handle the key bindings for changing channels. Are there any examples available for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a two way, if you want use native channel switch like "tuneUp" and "tuneDown" buttons, you can unregister buttons in your app and they will work as native:

```
function init() {

    var pluginAPI,
        tvKey;

    try {

        var nnaviPlugin = document.getElementById('pluginObjectNNavi');

        if (nnaviPlugin) {
            nnaviPlugin.SetBannerState(2);
        }

        pluginAPI = new Common.API.Plugin();
        tvKey = new Common.API.TVKeyValue();

        pluginAPI.setOffScreenSaver();

        pluginAPI.unregistKey(tvKey.KEY_CH_UP);
        pluginAPI.unregistKey(tvKey.KEY_CH_DOWN);

        pluginAPI.unregistKey(tvKey.KEY_VOL_UP);
        pluginAPI.unregistKey(tvKey.KEY_VOL_DOWN);
        pluginAPI.unregistKey(tvKey.KEY_MUTE);

        webapis.tv.window.getAvailableWindow(successCB, errorCB);

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Don't forget add plugins to html:

```
<object id="pluginPlayer" classid="clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-PLAYER" style="width: 0; height: 0; opacity: 0;"></object>
<object id="pluginObjectTVMW"classid="clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-TVMW" style="width: 0; height: 0; opacity: 0;"></object>
<object id="pluginObjectNNavi" classid="clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-NNAVI" style="width: 0; height: 0; opacity: 0;"></object>
```

Second way, catch keyDown events and use sdk methods:

```
webapis.tv.channel.tuneUp(successCB, errorCB, webapis.tv.channel.NAVIGATOR_MODE_ALL);
webapis.tv.channel.tuneDown(successCB, errorCB, webapis.tv.channel.NAVIGATOR_MODE_ALL);
```

and if you want go to chosen channel:

```
webapis.tv.channel.tune(channelObjFromEpg, successCB, errorCB);
```

Comment: I was able to get this working with the second way, catching keyDown events and using SDK methods. However I could not succeed in un-registering the buttons (the first method). Do you have an example of how this is used in a project (e.g. a complete reference project)? I'll accept the answer but any further info on unregistering buttons would be great.

Comment: May i know why i keep getting rendering error using this plugin ? The live video plays fine on simulator but not in real device!